# progress bar not showing properly

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I made a progress bar but using step active but each bar is separating at one line. Also it's not showing my text properly either.
Here is my html code:

```
`<div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="step active"></div>
    <div class="step active"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>`
```

CSS code:

```
 `.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }

.step {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 display: block;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 }

.step:after {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 5px;
left: 22px;
width: 225px;
height: 6px;
content: '';
}

.step:before {
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
}

 .step:nth-child(1):before {
 content: 'Delivery';
  }
 .step:nth-child(2):before {
 right: -40px;
 content: 'Confirmation';
 }
 .step:nth-child(3):before {
 right: -30px;
 content: 'Payment';
 }
 .step:nth-child(4):before {
  right: 0;
  content: 'Finish';
  }
```

Also i didn't write this whole code myself but found it from a website

Comment: Your `active` selector is not defined in CSS.